# Is calling the Palmer Station (Antarctica) via IRLP without prior arrangements acceptable practice?

Tags: internet, dx, etiquette

Until I can get an HF rig, I've been using my HT through a local repeater IRLP node. I've successfully made a few contacts doing that, but I recently noticed that Palmer Station in Antartica has an IRLP Node (#8838) listed. I tried making a contact, but it kept saying "connection error" and disconnected. The last time, I heard someone, but too scratchy to understand shortly before it disconnected.

My question is, is it accept to call that node without a prior arrangement, or it is reserved for the private use of the Hams living there?

If it is, is there any special procedure for doing such a contact?

I did verify that their local time was 10 am - 12 pm during the time I was trying to make contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I can tell, it's perfectly acceptable to use the Palmer IRLP node, but realize that it might not be connected all the time. It is probably a similar situation to the ISS, you just frequently won't get a response.